# Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true [JAVA]

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

We have a java application (spring boot + hibernate search + elastic search).
Application is working fine on elastic search version 6.8

Recently, we have created a new cluster in aws with version 7.10.2 and updated elastic search endpoint in my java application.

After updating the elastic search endpoint I am getting error Can't update put mapping *Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true* and due to this unable to start the server.

I am not sure where to set include_type_name=true because all the indexes gets created automatically with @Indexed.

Can someone please let us know how can we fix this issue ?

Thanks @yrodiere for your response.

I tried to upgrade below dependencies version but unfortunately not able to fix it.

**Previous Version:**

```
 compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:5.9.3.Final'
 compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-search-elasticsearch:5.9.3.Final'
 compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-search-elasticsearch-aws:5.9.3.Final'
```

**Updated version :**

```
 compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:5.9.3.Final 
 compile 'org.hibernate.search:hibernate-search-backend-elasticsearch:6.1.1.Final'    
 compile 'org.hibernate.search:hibernate-search-backend-elasticsearch-aws:6.1.1.Final'
```

**Note**: If I downgrade this org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:5.9.3.Final  then getting CE

am i missing something?

Comment: Hi @yrodiere - any thoughts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6692043/yrodiere

Comment: You're trying to use hibernate search 5.x and 6.x in the same application. This cannot work. Read the [migration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/migration/html_single/), and if you need a more detailed example for the dependencies, have a look at the [getting started guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#gettingstarted-dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using Hibernate Search 5.x. In Hibernate Search 5.x, the Elasticsearch integration [was experimental](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-integration) and [only compatible with Elasticsearch up to version 5.6](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/5.11/#compatibility).

The fact that your application was working fine with Elasticsearch 6.8 was pure luck: Hibernate Search 5.x was never intended to work with Elasticsearch 6+.

To upgrade to a more recent version of Elasticsearch, you must upgrade to [Hibernate Search 6.0](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/) (or later). The API is different, but there is a very detailed [migration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/migration/html_single/), and at least you will get production-ready (non-experimental) Elasticsearch integration (plus [tons of improvements](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/#whats-new)).

Note that Hibernate Search 6.x also requires upgrading to Hibernate ORM 5.4; see [this compatibility matrix](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/#compatibility).